# How to get PSGet up and running from scratch

Tags: powershell-v5.0

On a new build machine with PowerShell 5.0, how do I configure PSGet so it actually just works?

I think it needs me to tell it what package provider I want and then what repository? And I'm behind a proxy, too, so that complicates things.

When I installed NuGet into Visual Studio, it just worked immediately against nuget.org, but with PowerShellGet its like there's no default setup.

Answer (score 0):

I think someone forgot that `Install-PackageProvider` needs `-Proxy` and that's scuppered the whole thing for millions of people.